# DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs doesn't fire

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Windows form application.
C# 4.0.

I have a datgridview bound to MS SQL table on a windows form. There is a delete button on it as well. I want to delete a row when I select a row and click the button. It is well done.
But I want to add a remind before deleting action. However I found it is not working. It never fires the event dgv_UserDeletingRow.

```
private void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;
            // Delete Table here and successfully
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void dgv_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Row.IsNewRow)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Delete confirmation",
                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (res == DialogResult.No)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the "confirm with user" code into the `DeleteRow_Click` handler.